# How do I get page likes on Facebook? (Since May 1st's update)

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps

Since May 1st (2018), Facebook seems to have changed its developers tools and now requires a "verified" business account to be able to use many of their APIs calls. I am wondering if it's possible to use a normal "unverified" Facebook App's `app_id` and `app_secret` to get public information such as a page's `fan_count`. I used to be able to do this, but since May 1st I get this message:

> To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review.

Is there any way of getting the information I want without going through the (now) very long process of verifying an App?

I am particularly interested in doing this with PHP's SDK or pure HTTP call.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you can use a page token instead, if you own the page. if you don´t, it seems that you have to go through the review process.

Comment: While I am not sure if there is a way to do this, do be careful with the path you are looking for. If FaceBook wants people to ask them to use their APIs and you find a way to use them without FaceBook's permission. You could get in some legal trouble.

Comment: Thanks @Tyler, I'll keep it in mind and be careful!

Comment: @luschn, I see, but if the information is public anyway (a page's likes can be seen by anyone), why do I need to be the owner of the page to retrieve such information? Wouldn't it make sense to be able to get this kind of information by just using a normal API token?

Comment: just because it is public on facebook.com does not mean you are allowed to grab it...

Comment: @luschn, yeah, I see, it makes sense. But anyway I thought they would be ok allowing anyone to "grab" that info, as anyone _could_ grab it if they really wanted to.. But thanks anyway! :)